Deleting a database row using an entity with an embedded ID
I am working on an app that is utilizing JPA, Rest, Hibernate, Spring Boot, and running Java for the back end.
I am calling to this method from another method, to blow away the record if someone deletes the Items associated with the parameter.  I have logs that let me know the parameter ID is being passed in to the query, so the problem seems to stem from the query itself.  When I test my code is Swagger, I just keep getting a "Data Was Not Found" message.
This is my first time attempting to delete a record that has an Embedded Id, and I just can't seem to get the query to work. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the delete method where I am my query in:
 @Override
 @Transactional
  public void deleteParameterById(Long parameterId) {
 
    Query query = entityManager
     .createQuery("DELETE FROM ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.ParameterEntityId.parameterId = ?1");
     query.setParameter(1, parameterId)
     .executeUpdate();

 }

Here is the Embedded ID (ParameterEntityId.java):
@Embeddable
public class ParameterEntityId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "PARAMETER_ID")
  private Long parameterId;

  @Column(name = "PARAMETER_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID")
  private Long parameterAttributeTypeId;


Here is My Entity File (ParameterEntity.java):
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameter")
public class ParameterEntity {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ParameterEntityId parameterEntityId;

  @Column(name = "VALUE")
  private String value;


I find a lot of examples using JPA repositories, but that it not how this app is configured, we are using entities.
I initially just tried to write a native query and call straight to the DB table Parameters and select the parameter_cd directly so I could bypass this embedded key, (the DB uses a composite key of parameter_id and parameter_attribute_type_id) but when I tested it in Swagger, I just got a "processing" message and the query would never finish running.
I have also ensured the app has the proper permissions to edit and delete from the table.
here is my original native query:
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteParameterById(Long parameterId) {

      entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM *dbname(redacted)*.parameter WHERE parameter_id = ?1")
      .setParameter(1, parameterId).executeUpdate();
  
  }


Your query is wrong. JPQL uses the java properties, so if you want to access something across a reference, it is the property name you use (not the class name) just as you would in code. So "DELETE FROM ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.parameterEntityId.parameterId = ?1". You should have gotten a runtime error with your previous query though that points to the problem. If a native query isn't working though, you may have something else going wrong with the DB setup - does reads work? Turn logging on and verify your query results in SQL that is actually executed.

yes, the DB Reads and updates just fine, I just can't get a delete to work. Also, if I take the SQL from my native query and run in in SQL Developer, It works as intended.

Again, turn on logging and see what statements are being issued. You may also want to step through it in a debugger to find out where things are getting stuck, or if you have a bad exception handling somewhere in your code. Does a delete using an object instance work? This isn't a solution, but try using a "select pa from ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.parameterEntityId.parameterId = ?1" and then iterate over the results to remove each using em.remove  and see if it works (verify the SQL is issued and if it gets stuck somewhere). You may have a lock on a particular object in the DB or other issue

As already writtent in the comments by Chris, the query has to be fixed using the right case for the parameterEntityId attribute, so that you have:
Query query =
    entityManager.createQuery(
        "DELETE FROM ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.parameterEntityId.parameterId = ?1");

Using your original query, this exception is thrown:
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownPathException: Could not resolve attribute 'ParameterEntityId' of 'it.so.entity.ParameterEntity' [DELETE FROM ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.ParameterEntityId.parameterId = ?1]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:852)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.PathElementException: Could not resolve attribute 'ParameterEntityId' of 'it.so.entity.ParameterEntity'

Using the right query, Hibernate translates the jpql into this sql:
delete from parameter pe1_0 where pe1_0.parameter_id=?

that matches your native one, which in a unit test execution runs immediately with no errors.
Since, as you said, this query runs smoothly in SQLDeveloper, I suspect that when this runs in the application there is something that may lock the record on the db that occurrs during the rest endpoint call, between the controller and the deleteParameterById method. I suggest to check if there is something that runs before this delete method that may create this lock.

Try this instead:
Query query = entityManager
 .createQuery("DELETE FROM ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.ParameterEntityId.parameterId = :paramId");
 query.setParameter("paramId", parameterId).executeUpdate();


Why would named parameters work if positional ones don't? "pa.ParameterEntityId" doesn't exist in the model.

DELETE FROM ParameterEntity pa WHERE pa.ParameterEntityId.parameterId = ?1 is wrong actually. It can be just written as pa.ParameterEntityId.parameterId = ? and it will work.

First example I found (https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-query-parameters) shows using ‘?1’ as perfectly valid. I didn’t check the spec recently but your answer may be wrong. And you doubled down - “pa.ParameterEntityId” cannot work as there is no ParameterEntityId in the model. The property is parameterEntityId in the question definition so positional or named parameters can’t work
